# What types of site analytics are given at 25,000 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

I know that at 25,000 rep you get some access to site analytics, but even after reading [the page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), I don't understand exactly what types of things are given. What do Google Analytics entail? Can someone with 25k+ rep please let me know more information about what is given besides what is already there on [the page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)?

Comment: Crappy ones. I wouldn't get too excited

Comment: @Valorum - Way to be frank! :)

Comment: I wanted to depress people's expectations.

Comment: Yeah, I've never figured out what to do with the 25k tier stuff either. It's nice, but meh compared to, say, 20k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post numbers;

[image]

Vote Counts;

[image]

Site Traffic;

[image]

Site analytic and Traffic Sources;

[image]

All of which is basically pointless. Apparently SE would prefer that we not share the raw data (huh?) but is happy to share the analysis that results from it (huh?).